# How to properly reply on the email received?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, reply

Once email message is received, I send some reply to the user with GAE usage:

```
class EmailReplyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): # parse email details manually
    def post(self):
        msg = email.message_from_string(self.request.body)
        from_realname, from_emailaddr = email.utils.parseaddr(msg['from'])
        ...
        email = mail.EmailMessage()
        email.to = from_emailaddr
        ...
        email.send()

...
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_ah/mail/report@myappid\.appspotmail\.com', EmailReplyHandler),
```

What should I indicate in the reply that user's mail software will recognize that as reply? Should I keep the same subject and add `RE:` as prefix? What else? Is there any solution to use different subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on the email client.

You can try by parsing `Message-ID` header of the inbount mail and adding it to `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers of the outbout (your reply) mail.

There are other headers you could use, see [Sending Mail with Headers section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail_with_headers).

Comment: Thank you. Should I remove brackets (`<` and `>`) from the `Message-ID` when using that value in `In-Reply-To`? I tried to pass it as is, but looks like GMail doesn't recognize it.

Comment: I think it should be as is. Just did a quick search on matching gmail thread: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/how-does-email-threading-work-in-gmail.html

Comment: Thanks. Found the same description about the subject on google pages - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en